# I want to go other activity when the button is pressed

Tags: java, android

my problem is on line 39 that is null exception

```
btnDetail = findViewById(R.id.btn_move_activity);
        btnDetail.setOnClickListener(this);
```

my code

```
package com.example.aplikasimoviecataloguesub1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnDetail;
    private String[] dataName;
    private String[] dataDescription;
    private String[] dataDate;
    private TypedArray dataPhoto;
    private MoviesAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Movie> movies;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new MoviesAdapter(this);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.lv_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        prepare();
        addItem();

        btnDetail = findViewById(R.id.btn_move_activity);
        btnDetail.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    private void prepare() {
        dataName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.data_name);
        dataDescription = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.data_description);
        dataDate = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.data_date);
        dataPhoto = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.data_photo);
    }

    private void addItem() {
        movies = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataName.length; i++) {
            Movie movie = new Movie();
            movie.setPhoto(dataPhoto.getResourceId(i, -1));
            movie.setName(dataName[i]);
            movie.setDate(dataDate[i]);
            movie.setDescription(dataDescription[i]);
            movies.add(movie);
        }
        adapter.setMovies(movies);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_move_activity:
                Intent moveIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                startActivity(moveIntent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and it is error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.aplikasimoviecataloguesub1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: check that there is a button with id equals to `btn_move_activity` in your `activity_main` layout

Comment: You should post also your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure R.id.btn_move_activity this id's view is from R.layout.activity_main this file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `id` you are passing for your `button`. According to the crash, you are accessing the `button` before it is initialised. It's like accessing something which doesn't exist in the memory. Hence **NPE**. Also, make it a habit of **initialising** all the `views` immediately after you call `setContentView()`. With this habit, you can avoid ***NPE's  at-least for the views***. Refer code below :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();
        initListeners();

        adapter = new MoviesAdapter(this);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        prepare();
        addItem();

    }



    private void initViews() {
        listView = findViewById(R.id.lv_list);
        btnDetail = findViewById(R.id.btn_move_activity);

    }

    private void initListeners() {
        btnDetail.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Let me know if you have any confusion. Happy Coding :)

Comment: em can you tell me what to do

Comment: Replace your onCreate() method with above. Also copy initViews()  & initListeners() method as above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your variables to the relevant view elements, as follows

```
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_list);

    btnDetail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_move_activity);
```